# What credential are used by report using direct query or live connection?

Tags: powerbi

Power bi report in the import mode uses the credential configured in the gateway to access the underlying sql server database.

What credential is used when report uses:

1. Direct query mode to sql server db
2. Live connection to SSAS cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live connect to AAS and Power BI Datasets uses AAD auth with the identity of the report user.  There is no option to use a stored credential.

Live connect to SSAS connects through the On-Prem gateway using a stored credential of an SSAS admin and passes the end user identity using the EffectiveUserName connection string parameter.  See [Manage your data source - Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas)

For DirectQuery to SQL Server SSO is optional.

[image]

Comment: For SSAS and Direct query - do these both support passing report user credential for example to ensure row level security can be effective?

Comment: Yes.  Both support using the report user's identity to connect to the data source.